# In Grails, is there a way to control plugin order relative to resources.groovy?

Tags: grails

We use Weceem, which uses loadBefore inside of WeceemGrailsPlugin like this:

```
def loadBefore = ['controllers', 'ckeditor', 'elasticsearch']
```

What happens is, WeceemGrailsPlugin gets processed, then our application's resources.groovy, then ElasticsearchGrailsPlugin gets processed after that.

The problem is, I need to override one of the beans in elasticsearch inside our app's resources.groovy, so I need it to process the ElasticsearchGrailsPlugin doWithSpring block before our resources.groovy.

Is there any way to force that behavior in resources.groovy somehow?  Some kind of 'loadAfter' capability we could use to force it to load elasticsearch first, or another workaround to force it?

Comment: Note: it turned out that even though the elasticsearch plugin was initialized after the app's resources.groovy, it still seemed to use my bean definition instead of that for the plugin.  Not sure why, but it solves this particular problem.  The question remains, though.